# Android Support Repository doesn't show up in Android Studio SDK Manager

Tags: android, android-studio, android-espresso

As I am trying to use Espresso Android test tools, I need to add Android Support Repository in my SDK, but I cannot find it, nor can I find it standalone manager. SDKs and Android Studio are the latest version.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Have you Tryied `Launch Standalone SDK Manager` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the SDK Manager, the **Android Support Repository** is now called **Local Maven repository for Support Libraries**.

Comment: @x50978 Mark the answer if it solves your question. it can help other users.